# Kubernetes Template UML models

Tags: kubernetes, model, containers, uml

Is there any place where I can find the UML representation of Kubernetes Templatesand constructs - Pod, ReplicaSet, Job etc.

Comment: Your question is off-topic. Consult the help on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 3):

There is few diagrams you can find.

For example how does the Container Deployment work:
[image: Container Deployment]
How does the Kubernetes Object work:

[image: Kubernetes Object]
How does the architecture work:

[image: architecture]
[image: architecture]

I also do recommend reading [Kubernetes in three diagrams](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio/kubernetes-in-three-diagrams-6aba8432541c) by [Tsuyoshi Ushio](https://medium.com/@tsuyoshiushio) and [Getting Started With Kubernetes](https://dzone.com/refcardz/kubernetes-essentials?chapter=1).